# Capture properties of a dynamically added Kivy button

Tags: python, kivy

I have an app created in Python and Kivy that has a screen that once accessed creates some buttons dynamically. I would like to know how to capture the text of the button that was clicked.

Python:

```
def on_enter(self):
    lista_series =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
    for i in lista_series:
        self.ids.grid.add_widget(Button(text=str(i)))
```

When clicking any button, I would like the text of the clicked button to return.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set a function through on_press that will send the pressed instance (the button) as a parameter:

```
def on_enter(self):
    lista_series =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
    for i in lista_series:
        button = Button(text=str(i), on_press=self.foo)
        self.ids.grid.add_widget(button)

def foo(self, instance):
    print(instance.text)
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much, that's exactly what you needed.